# THREE.GLTFLoader - scope.manager is undefined

Tags: three.js

I am using this GTFLoader:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

On Firefox I get: `scope.manager is undefined`

On Chrome I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemStart' of undefined`

Thank you

Comment: What version of `three.js` are you using? You have to ensure that the version of `GLTFLoader` matches to the core library version.

Comment: I think I found the right GLTFLoader, however now I get `object3d is undefined` at `THREEx.DomEvents`. I think the version Im using is this one: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.js

Comment: `THREEx.DomEvents` is a third-party library and not related to the core. I'm not sure but it seems the project is not supported anymore: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents : Consider to implement interaction in your 3D app differently.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the console in your project you can see the ThreeJS version in the very first line:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer 96

Make sure your GLTFLoader has the same version. So in my case it's 96.

[https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/**r96**/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js](https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r96/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js)

Make sure you modify the bold part of the URL to your ThreeJS Version to get the right code.